# Symfony2 phpunit gives 503 error

Tags: symfony, phpunit

I signed up to GitHub and forked [Symfony2](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/tree/master/src/Symfony). I tried to run the Symfony2 tests according to the [instructions](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/contributing/code/tests.html). I type `> phpunit` but every time, after some tests, I suddenly get **out of memory** message:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 40 bytes) in ...\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\HeaderBag.php on line 37
```

Then, the tests result is something like that:

```
503 Service Unavailable503 Service Unavailable503 Service Unavailable503 Service
Unavailable503 Service Unavailable503 Service Unavailable503 Service Unavailable
```

What may be causing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into the same problem using the 2.0 branch. The full set of tests require approx. 163Mb of memory and like first answer said php defaults to 128M. You have two options.

Change the default max memory allocation to something greater than 163Mb.

`memory_limit = 200M in php.ini`

or

- copy `phpunit.xml.dist` to `phpunit.xml`
- alter the attribute bootstrap to read `bootstrap="tests/local-bootstrap.php"`
- add an entry into your `.gitignore` for `tests/local-bootstrap.php`
- create local-bootstrap.php with something like:

local-bootstrap.php

```
<?php
    ini_set('memory_limit', '200M'); // might need to adjust the value
    require 'bootstrap.php'          // no need to duplicate the bootstrap
```

This way allows you to add local changes without having to worry about git tacking any modifications to files that are local to your machine.

Answer (score 0):

That is because the script exceeded the maximum amount of memory defined in php.ini

By default is 128M (134217728 bytes)

Here is explained http://php.net/memory-limit